# Secure way of hosting Node.js on windows server

Tags: node.js, iis, hosting

I need to host Node App on the Window Server using IIS. IIS provides only two ways iisnode module and reverse proxy using Application request Routing.

the problem here is that issnode is no longer being maintained by Microsoft and isn't secure to use, same as the case with reverse proxy.

What's the secure way of hosting Node.js app on Windows server?

Comment: you could try to use the reverse proxy. A reverse proxy can hide the topology and characteristics of your back-end servers by removing the need for direct internet access to them. You can place your reverse proxy in an internet-facing DMZ, but hide your web servers inside a non-public subnet.

Comment: I doubt very much that reverse proxy functionality is insecure and not being maintained by Microsoft in IIS.